# Is christian communism a real political system?

Tags: ideology, communism, religion

Is christian communism a real political system? If so, what are the main points defended by it?

Comment: The answer linked in above comment addresses this in detail - in short, "original" Marxism isn't compatible with official organized religion (though some of Marxist offshoots like Liberation Theology (made famous by Obama pre-election scandal) and flavors of Marxist  Islam in Middle East married the two); however non-Marxist communism can be Christianity based, e.g. Muenster Anabaptists or any other communalism often rooted (for Christians) often based on Acts 2:44 or 4:32.

Comment: Also closely related: ["How can a classless society exist with religion" on this site](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10485/how-can-a-classless-society-exist-with-religion/10488#10488) and ["Christian Communism" on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_communism)